# Aligning text with floated :before icon

Tags: html, css

I am working on a button style for Azure Active Directory B2C. Azure automatically provides the following content

```
<div class="options">
    <div>
        <button class="accountButton firstButton" id="AmazonExchange" tabindex="1">Amazon</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="accountButton" id="LinkedInExchange" tabindex="1">LinkedIn</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="accountButton" id="FacebookExchange" tabindex="1">Facebook</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="accountButton" id="GoogleExchange" tabindex="1">Google+</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="accountButton" id="MicrosoftAccountExchange" tabindex="1">Microsoft</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using FontAwesome and :before css magic, I am able to add an icon, and fix width the button

```
.accountButton {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #5x05050;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#AmazonExchange:before {
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    content: "\f270";
    //font-size: large;
    float:left;
    width:32px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

This is nice, but I would like the icons to be just a bit bigger. However, increasing the size of the FontAwesome item to large causes the primary text to go up, as it is aligned to the top of the float:left.

[image]

I've tried a variety of valign combinations with no luck. I cannot change the html (as it is dynamically generated). How can I center the "Amazon" with the larger icon? (Notice that the Amazon text is now higher than the LinkedIn and other text.)

---

Attempted jsfiddle, doesn't look quite the same, but should show the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/tofutim/0637yknj/9/

Comment: With float you will need to adjust the offset by using margin-top or bottom 2px, -2px etc, vertical-align works only on inline level elements, you can also try flexbox.

Comment: I can try that, though I'm concerned about using very specific offsets to accomplish this. What if the font size changes?

Comment: An example of using inline block - https://jsfiddle.net/vpvc87zd/ and with flexbox - https://jsfiddle.net/ry7ge6ga/

Comment: that works for me! if you write up the solution i can select it.

Comment: Posted exactly the same code as in the demos plus some descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a dynamic way to adjust valign with floating elements. You can either use `display: inline-block;` + `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.accountButton {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.accountButton:before {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpvc87zd/)**

Or, use `display: flex;` + `align-items: center;`

```
.accountButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.accountButton:before {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry7ge6ga/)**

The `line-height` part is just to make the buttons a bit taller, you can also use `padding-top` + `padding-bottom` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a `line-height` to `.accountButton` might correct this issue for you. This will vertically centre text within the given vertical space, and in your example should be equal to the desired height of the button.

Try something like: `line-height: 30px;`.